# Redirect to URL and append hash at the end

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to redirect to a route/URL and append a hash at the end, but Aurelia keeps telling me `ERROR [app-router] Error: Route not found: /#the-hash-i-added`.

Here's the very basic code I'm using to redirect to a new route inside my authorize pipeline step:

`return next.cancel(new Redirect(this.router.generate('home')));`

This works fine and redirects non authorized users to the home page. However, I'd like them to end up at one specific part on the home page, hence the hash.

Now, since the `Redirect` class takes a URL as its argument, I figured I'd simply add the hash at the end, like so:

`return next.cancel(new Redirect(this.router.generate('home') + '#hash-where-i-want-to-end-up'));`

And while Aurelia successfully redirects to the correct URL (`/#hash-where-i-want-to-end-up` is set in the browser's URL bar) it still throws the aforementioned error and does not render the page.

I actually managed to hack around this by manually adding the hash after the redirect occurred, with a `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    window.location.hash = '#hash-where-i-want-to-end-up';
});

return next.cancel(new Redirect(this.router.generate('home')));
```

But not only does this feel like a dirty, dirty hack, it doesn't work well in other scenarios.

So, my question is, how can I redirect to a route and append a hash at the end?

Needless to say I'm using `pushState: true` and `hashChange: false` in my application.

**Edit:** I couldn't get a `pushState` app running on gist.run for some reason, but I set up a completely new Aurelia CLI project with this very basic setup:

**app.js**

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Router, Redirect} from 'aurelia-router';

export class App {
    configureRouter (config, router) {
        config.title = 'Test';
        config.options.pushState = true;
        config.options.hashChange = false;
        config.options.root = '/';

        config.map([
            {
                route: [''],
                name: 'home',
                moduleId: 'resources/elements/home',
                title: 'Home'
            },
            {
                route: ['about'],
                name: 'about',
                moduleId: 'resources/elements/about',
                title: 'About',
                settings: {auth: true}
            },
        ]);

        config.addAuthorizeStep(AuthorizeStep);
    }
}

@inject(Router)
class AuthorizeStep {
    constructor (router) {
        this.router = router;
    }

    run (navigationInstruction, next) {
        // Never allow access to auth routes
        if (navigationInstruction.getAllInstructions().some(i => (i.config.settings && i.config.settings.auth))) {
            return next.cancel(new Redirect(this.router.generate('home') + '#foo'));
        }

        return next();
    }
}
```

**app.html**

```
<template>
    <a route-href="route: home">Home</a> | <a route-href="route: about">About</a>
    <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

**home.js**

```
export class Home {}
```

**home.html**

```
<template>
    <h1>Home</h1>
</template>
```

**about.js**

```
export class About {
}
```

**about.html**

```
<template>
    <h1>About</h1>
</template>
```

As you can see, going to /about should redirect you back to /#foo, and while that indeed works (the user ends up at /#foo) I get the same error: `vendor-bundle.js:14169 ERROR [app-router] Error: Route not found: /#foo`

Comment: just tried `return next.cancel(new Redirect('/#bar-bar'));` in my app, it did not give me any error. Are you able to reproduce it in a gist-run?

Comment: @huocp I couldn't get a `pushState` example running on gist.run for some reason, but I've updated the question with a full example based on a completely new Aurelia CLI project.

Comment: yeah, I can see that now. Now I am wondering why my app doesn't have the issue :-s

Comment: There is no problem to use in `config.AuthorizeStep`, but doesn't work in `canActivate`. By looking into the error in aurelia-router source code, it preprocesses incoming url by stripping out query parameters `"?a=1&b=2"`, but not the hash. It looks like a opportunity for a PR.

Comment: In my real app it's inside an `AuthorizeStep` it doesn't work. So, no, it doesn't seem to work anywhere.

Comment: @huocp I updated the question again (and tried my local example again) now with the redirect inside an AuthorizeStep. It still does not work :/ Are you saying it works fine in your app? Could you set up a gist.run with a working example?

Comment: Now my exact code on `config.AuthorizeStep` doesn't work anymore, I am quite confused. I don't think I touched anything in last two days.

Comment: Well that's weird :P Personally I've never been able to get a redirect with a hash to work. Inside an authorize step or not.

Comment: Hey @powerbuoy, Did you figure out how to do that?

`My issue: Need to create a link that redirects user to some page that is prefilled with data that the user provided on first page.  `
Now comes the confusing part, I have to add hash at the end of URL to change the state of redirected page. 
Can you please help me with that?